# How to change the Tor exit node programmatically to get a new IP?

Tags: tor

I have Tor running on my computer, and I need to change the Tor exit node every five minutes.
For example, if I start using Tor via some exit node, then in 5 minutes I want Tor to change to an exit node with a different IP address. How can I do this?

Tor, as far as I know, is listening to port 8051  on localhost.

What commands can I send to this port to make Tor build a new chain, so that I can get another IP address?

Answer (score 54):

**Method 1: HUP**

```
sudo killall -HUP tor
```

Then [check that your IP has changed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95910/command-for-determining-my-public-ip) with:

```
curl --socks5 127.0.0.1:9050 http://checkip.amazonaws.com/
```

Tested in Ubuntu 17.10 with `sudo apt-get install tor` version 1.6.0-5.

`sudo` is needed since the process is started by root by default.

What an HUP signal does exactly to the Tor daemon is documented at: https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/control-spec.txt?id=03aaace9bd9459b0d4bf22a75012acf39d07bcec#n394 and is equivalent to sending some command through the command port.

Browser Bundle 5.0.5 is not affected by this, only daemon ports like the default 9050, which is not used by the TBB. For that use case see: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1071/how-can-a-new-circuit-happen-without-closing-all-tabs

If you are deploying an army of Tor IPs [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18895491/895245) you can selectively send:

```bash
kill -HUP $PID
```

We can select the PID by port as per: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106561/finding-the-pid-of-the-process-using-a-specific-port E.g. to change IP of the Tor listening in at port 9050:

```bash
kill -HUP "$(sudo netstat -nlp | awk '$4~":9050"{ gsub(/\/.*/,"",$7); print $7 }')"
```

**Method 2: control port**

Mentioned by [kat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11354585/895245):

```bash
(echo authenticate '""'; echo signal newnym; echo quit) | nc localhost 9051
```

but for that to work on Ubuntu 17.10 you **must first**:

- enable the control port by uncommenting:

  ```
  ControlPort 9051
  ```

  from `/etc/tor/torrc`
- Set the empty password, otherwise it gives `515 Authentication failed: Wrong length on authentication cookie.`. First run:

  ```bash
  tor --hash-password ''
  ```

  This outputs something like:

  ```
  16:D14CC89AD7848B8C60093105E8284A2D3AB2CF3C20D95FECA0848CFAD2
  ```

  Now on `/etc/tor/torrc` update the line:

  ```
  HashedControlPassword 16:D14CC89AD7848B8C60093105E8284A2D3AB2CF3C20D95FECA0848CFAD2
  ```
- Restart Tor:

  ```
  sudo service tor restart
  ```

**Related threads**

- https://superuser.com/questions/449060/tor-how-to-have-different-ip-address-for-every-page-request
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/499995/change-ip-address-which-is-given-by-tor-using-the-terminal
- https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/100/can-tor-be-used-with-applications-other-than-web-browsers
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/95910/command-for-determining-my-public-ip

Comment: with control port, the nc command displays "250 OK 250 OK 250 closing connection" but my Tor IP address doesn't change, any idea?

Comment: @baptx sorry, I don't know what to do. If you find out, please ping me.

Comment: And how to do the **Method 2** in macOS?

Comment: What are the benefits of method 1 over 2 ? (and 2 over 1 ?)

Comment: @UlysseBN signal is slightly easier to do, port would allow more general controls however I think

Answer (score 44):

```bash
(echo authenticate '""'; echo signal newnym; echo quit) | nc localhost 9051
```

Comment: For that to work, you must first enable the control port like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33726166/895245

Comment: Great trick, but note that this doesn't _guarantee_ a new IP - just a change of exit node - which may of course result in the same one again ;)

Answer (score 10):

This question seems to come up pretty frequently ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17013707/how-can-i-change-my-tor-process-endpoint-in-stem), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987518/how-to-request-new-tor-identity-in-terminal)) so I just added a [FAQ entry](https://stem.torproject.org/faq.html#how-do-i-request-a-new-identity-from-tor) for it. As mentioned earlier you can do this via a NEWNYM signal. Here's an example for doing it via [stem](https://stem.torproject.org/)...

```py
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller

with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:
  controller.authenticate()
  controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
```

Answer (score 8):

yeah, that's 1 (i mean =true =))) that tor does change ip every 10 minutes
but! if i restart tor - i'll get a new ip even in this 10minutes interval.
so i was thinking about making tor to send this "change_ip" request manually.
see this code (written according to http://en.linuxreviews.org/HOWTO_use_the_Internet_anonymously_using_Tor_and_Privoxy)

```
procedure ChangeIp;
var
  sck:TIdTCPClient;
begin
  sck:=TIdTCPClient.Create(nil);
  try
    sck.Host:='127.0.0.1';
    sck.Port:=10051;
    sck.Connect;
    sck.SendCmd('authenticate','');
    if sck.LastCmdResult.Code='250' then
    begin
      sck.SendCmd('signal newnym','');
    end;
  finally
    sck.Free;
  end;
end;
```

and accornig to [https://tor-svn.freehaven.net/svn/torctl/trunk/doc/howto.txt] i can write a controler that will change tor's conf on the fly.
by default it is not enebled (i mean this ability), but i can make tor client listen to some port for accepting commands using torrc...if i'm not mistaken...again=)

**!!! where the hell torrc is on my pc?**

In C:\Users\geekman\AppData\Roaming\Tor i could,n fing it
i got vista.

Comment: By default there IS no torrc, you have to manually create one (and I recommend reading the entire manual first)... unfortunately the console is suppressed in windows without corresponding via python code or using some other means of piping its output into the console.

Answer (score 4):

I've made a shell script for myself that also lets you do this remotely (if Tor server is running on another machine).

It's available here: https://gist.github.com/kirelagin/9667900.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply type or insert in your bash script:

```
service tor reload
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have access to the control port, you could use a different circuit which changes your IP*. This can be done by specifying a different socks username:

```
$ curl -x "socks5://circuit1@127.0.0.1:9050" "https://ifconfig.io/ip"
109.70.100.34

$ curl -x "socks5://circuit2@127.0.0.1:9050" "https://ifconfig.io/ip"
209.222.101.251

$ curl -x "socks5://circuit3@127.0.0.1:9050" "https://ifconfig.io/ip"
54.37.19.83
```

If you want to reuse a specific IP at some point you can use the same username you used before to get that IP again.

* The exit node will be random every time and there is a slight chance you'll get the same IP twice in a row.

Correct me if I'm wrong, I'm not a Tor expert, but this works for me.

Answer (score 2):

You have no control over the routing in the tor network (if you had, someone could abuse this feature). But tor already switches the route roughly every 10 minutes (at least according to the [German Wikipedia article](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_%28Netzwerk%29)).

Comment: This isn't completely true, for those who stumble upon this thread. You can use the control port and modify some internal tor settings to basically create your own circuits. http://www.thesprawl.org/memdump/?entry=8 can get you started.

Answer (score 1):

I have done something different here... i wrote a PHP program that can communicate with linux shell. The program would restart tor in regular intervals.

So when tor is restarted it gets a new IP....  Yeah.....!!

```php
exec("/etc/init.d/tor restart",$ioOut);
print_r($ioOut); //output from shell after executing the command
sleep(25);
```

You can also write a shell script to do this.

I am now in search of a windows option to do this. The problem is .. in windows Tor is a service which cannot be restarted.

Comment: Sending a command to Tor is much faster and secure than rebooting the whole daemon

Comment: Clain Dsilva , could you give us an example? I am looking for that command and still didn't get it....

Comment: @HoNgOuRu the Linux command would be "/etc/init.d/tor restart"

Answer (score 1):

[Advtor](http://advtor.sourceforge.net) gives you access over almost all advanced settings which works over tor network.

Answer (score 0):

I've wrote a library to control Tor with PHP. It is installable with Composer and allows to change the exit node.

Of course it's free software: http://dunglas.fr/2013/02/php-torcontrol-a-library-to-control-tor/