# How can I force Tor to use a new identity without using Vidalia?

Tags: delphi, tor

I am using [Tor](http://www.torproject.org/) in my project. How can I force Tor to use a new identity from my program?

Comment: @Andreas - http://www.torproject.org - In short, network for anonymous browsing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change tor exit node programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969958/how-to-change-tor-exit-node-programmatically)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Open a telnet connection to the control port of your Tor service and send it `SIGNAL NEWNYM`.

I expect you could use any Delphi telnet library. My first choice would be [Indy](http://www.indyproject.org/); make sure you have the [latest version](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Download/svn.EN.aspx).

Comment: thanks for reply sir , can u please write some basic example how to send SIGNAL NEWNYM using indy ?

Comment: ok here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992774/how-to-use-idtelent1-to-send-commands