# How to change Tor identity in Python?

Tags: python, tor

I have the following script:

```
import socks
import socket
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
import urllib2

print(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.ifconfig.me/ip").read())
```

which uses tor and [SocksiPy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/socksipy/)

Now I want to change tor identity with each request, for example:

```
for i in range(0, 10):
   #somehow change tor identity
   print(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.ifconfig.me/ip").read())
```

How can I do this?

Comment: From Bash: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969958/how-to-change-tor-exit-node-programmatically/33726166

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Today, I have searched a lot about this question, and finally managed to answer myself. But before I need to say that pirvoxy and tor should be configured correctly. First script, then a little bit about configuration:

```
import urllib2
from TorCtl import TorCtl

proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http" : "127.0.0.1:8118"})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support) 

def newId():
    conn = TorCtl.connect(controlAddr="127.0.0.1", controlPort=9051, passphrase="your_password")
    conn.send_signal("NEWNYM")

for i in range(0, 10):
    print "case "+str(i+1)
    newId()
    proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http" : "127.0.0.1:8118"})
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)
    print(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.ifconfig.me/ip").read())
```

Above script gets new IP and checks it from ifconfig.me web site. About configuration:
We need [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/). to use TOR with HTTP connections, privoxy should work with tor. We can do it by adding thi to /etc/privoxy/config file:

```
forward-socks5 / localhost:9050 . #dot is important at the end
```

then we configure ControlPort in /etc/tor/torrc file. We need just uncomment this line:

```
ControlPort 9051
## If you enable the controlport, be sure to enable one of these
## authentication methods, to prevent attackers from accessing it.
HashedControlPassword 16:872860B76453A77D60CA2BB8C1A7042072093276A3D701AD684053EC4C
```

then we just restart tor:

```
/etc/init.d/tor restart
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution but I have a small question: why do we need Privoxy here? Why can not I use SocksiPy as in your question?

Comment: I had problems which I also asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925381/python-script-exception-with-tor

Comment: @MikhailD There is no problem. For future readers: Just use SOCKS directly (without Privoxy).

Comment: What type of hash is used above?

Comment: Sorry for bumping this. For those searching for the hash password details, you can generate a different hash for a password different than `'your_password'` by executing the command `tor --hash-password "<new_password>"` and noting the new hash from the resulting output.

Answer (score 35):

Tor wrote a new TOR control library in Python, [stem](https://stem.torproject.org/index.html). It can be found on [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stem/1.1.0). They provide some nice tutorials how to work with it, [one](https://stem.torproject.org/faq.html#how-do-i-request-a-new-identity-from-tor) of them explains how to change your identity:

```
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller

with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:
  controller.authenticate()
  controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
```

Make sure your config is [correct](https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/the_little_relay_that_could.html).

Comment: @AdrianB B it gives error "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

Comment: I can't get this (or anything else with stem) to work on Windows

Comment: I know this is an old post, but just to clarify: if the machine "refuses" the connection, your port isn't correct, or you don't have Tor running

Answer (score 15):

Another simple solution, no external libraries required, works for both IPv4 and IPv6:

```
import socket

try:
    tor_c = socket.create_connection((TOR_CTRL_HOST, TOR_CTRL_PORT))
    tor_c.send('AUTHENTICATE "{}"\r\nSIGNAL NEWNYM\r\n'.format(TOR_CTRL_PWD))
    response = tor_c.recv(1024)
    if response != '250 OK\r\n250 OK\r\n':
        sys.stderr.write('Unexpected response from Tor control port: {}\n'.format(response))
except Exception, e:
    sys.stderr.write('Error connecting to Tor control port: {}\n'.format(repr(e)))
```

Comment: The socket class does have a connect() method that accepts a tuple, call socket.create_connection() instead.  My code looks like tor_ctrl = socket.create_connection(('127.0.0.1', '9151'))
tor_ctrl.send('AUTHENTICATE "{}"\r\nSIGNAL NEWNYM\r\n'.format('tor_control_pass')) # control password

Comment: I have tried this but get this error: Error connecting to Tor control port: error(61, 'Connection refused'). Any ideas?

Comment: I tried this and get following error--"Unexpected response from Tor control port: 515 Authentication failed: Password did not match HashedControlPassword *or*
authentication cookie.". I type in the password as following format--"16:7FA1766AE1DC149A603309B1BF8EBBAAA3F44C237898EF82D19908BD9‌​2"

Comment: I also tried this and getting `Error connecting to Tor control port: TypeError("a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'")`

Answer (score 4):

[This is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qTc8Vqn57pM&index=5&list=PL2YTY3kFME_eC2uHd28JjCXseGN809UQQ) where im using STEM, SockSipy, Tor 100% working :)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socks
import socket
import time
from stem.control import Controller
from stem import Signal
import urllib2
import sys

def info():
    print "[*] Welcome to Chart-Cheat Script"
    print "[*] This script works with running TOR only"
    print "[*] usage is chartcheat.py domain"
    print "[*] argument domain must be in format www.example.com"
    print "[*] Example: chartcheat.py www.example.com"
    return

if len(sys.argv)==2:
    info();
    counter = 0
    url = str(sys.argv[1]);
    with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:
        controller.authenticate()
        socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)
        socket.socket = socks.socksocket
        #visiting url in infinite loop      
        while True:
            urllib2.urlopen("http://"+url)
            counter=counter+1
            print "Page " + url + " visited = " + str(counter)
            #wait till next identity will be available
            controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
            time.sleep(controller.get_newnym_wait())            
else:
    info();
```

In case you are running python3, urllib package in python3 will be the same as urllib2 package in python2.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable tor control server by uncommenting few lines in

```
/etc/tor/torrc
```

And use stem library to send NEWNYM signal to change circuit.

```
controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
```

[You can read tutorial here.](https://sickyoon.com/2016/how-to-route-traffic-and-control-tor-network-with-python/)

Comment: Define `few lines` and the tutorial link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

you can write something like this :

```
def renew_connection():
    with Controller.from_port(port=9051) as controller:
        controller.authenticate(password='password')
        controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
        controller.close()

def request_tor(url, headers):
    renew_connection()
    session = requests.session()
    session.proxies = {}
    session.proxies['http'] = 'socks5h://localhost:9050'
    print((session.get(url)).text)
```

Comment: Could you help to make this answer more useful by clarifying on why this would fix the issue?

Comment: Each time you send a new request, the signal gives you a new ip and after every 4 seconds you can add a time.sleep(4) to have a new ip for each request and you can use the fake_useragent library to create fake agents for you randomly.
@SimasJoneliunas

Answer (score -2):

The following could work:

```
for i in range(0, 10):
   #somehow change tor identity
   socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050+i)
   socket.socket = socks.socksocket

   print(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.ifconfig.me/ip").read())
```

You basically set set the proxy prior to making each connection. I am asuming that you have different proxies for different IPs since you have not stated how you intend to change the IP

Comment: I just want to make request with different IP using tor, I mean in random time interval, I need to use changeTorIdentity() function. I need this changeTorIdentity() function.