# Python script Exception with Tor

Tags: python, tor

I have the following script which uses [SocksiPY](http://sourceforge.net/projects/socksipy/)

and Tor:

```
from TorCtl import TorCtl

import socks
import socket
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

import urllib2
import sqlite3
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

def newId():
    conn = TorCtl.connect(controlAddr="127.0.0.1", controlPort=9051, passphrase="123")
    TorCtl.Connection.send_signal(conn, "NEWNYM")

newId()

print(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.ifconfig.me/ip").read())
```

This code should change Tor identity but it waits for some time and gives the following error:

```
tuple index out of range
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "template.py", line 16, in <module>
    newId()
  File "template.py", line 14, in newId
    TorCtl.Connection.send_signal(conn, "NEWNYM")
TypeError: unbound method send_signal() must be called with Connection instance as first argument (got NoneType instance instead)
```

But above script is divided into 2 separate scripts:

```
import socks
import socket
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

import urllib2
import sqlite3
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

print(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.ifconfig.me/ip").read())
```

AND:

```
from TorCtl import TorCtl
def newId():
    conn = TorCtl.connect(controlAddr="127.0.0.1", controlPort=9051, passphrase="123")
    TorCtl.Connection.send_signal(conn, "NEWNYM")

newId()
```

When second script is called then first is called it is ok. Can anyone explain what is the problem and how to fix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anonymous explained very well this socket overwrite, answer is almost perfect except you have to **close the control socket**. It is safer because of the TorCtl event loop, but I have to look deeper in the TorCtl code to understand this event loop.

To summarize your code becomes:

```
from TorCtl import TorCtl

import socks
import socket
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)

import urllib2
import sqlite3
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

__originalSocket = socket.socket

def newId():
    ''' Clean circuit switcher

    Restores socket to original system value.
    Calls TOR control socket and closes it
    Replaces system socket with socksified socket
    '''
    socket.socket = __originalSocket
    conn = TorCtl.connect(controlAddr="127.0.0.1", controlPort=9051, passphrase="123")
    TorCtl.Connection.send_signal(conn, "NEWNYM")
    conn.close()
    socket.socket = socks.socksocket

newId()

print(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.ifconfig.me/ip").read())
```

Answer (score 2):

The connection to the control port fails, and `conn` is assigned the value which Python sockets uses to indicate failure (which is apparently of type `NoneType`).

The reason is that in the statement `socket.socket = socks.socksocket`, apparently you're replacing the default socket object or class with one which transparently proxies everything through Tor, which that makes the program try to proxy your control port connection.

The solution is to only perform `socket.socket = socks.socksocket` *after* you've opened the control connection (and keep that connection around if you need it later) or save the original `socket.socket` value so you can switch between values as needed.