# SocksiPy fails when connecting throug Tor

Tags: python, urllib2, socks, tor, httplib

Tried the 3 following methods to control Tor:

- using TorCtl/urllib2: [Python script Exception with Tor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925381/python-script-exception-with-tor?rq=1)
- using socks/httplib: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDsmVH7eJCs
- using socks/urllib2: [Python urllib over TOR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148589/python-urllib-over-tor)

Each of them fails w/ same error (tried to make it as clear as possible):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "tor.py", line 26, in <module>
  print(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.ifconfig.me/ip").read())

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py"
line 127, in urlopen
  return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
line 404, in open
  response = self._open(req, data)
line 422, in _open
  '_open', req)
line 382, in _call_chain
  result = func(*args)
line 1214, in http_open
  return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
line 1181, in do_open
  h.request(req.get_method(), req.get_selector(), req.data, headers)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py"
line 973, in request
  self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
line 1007, in _send_request
  self.endheaders(body)
line 969, in endheaders
  self._send_output(message_body)
line 829, in _send_output
  self.send(msg)
line 791, in send
  self.connect()
line 772, in connect
  self.timeout, self.source_address)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py"
line 562, in create_connection
  sock.connect(sa)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SocksiPy_branch-1.01-py2.7.egg/socks.py"
line 392, in connect
  self.__negotiatesocks5(destpair[0],destpair[1])
line 199, in __negotiatesocks5
  self.sendall("\x05\x01\x00")
line 165, in sendall
  socket.socket.sendall(self, bytes)
```

**... last error repeating a lot of times and then ...**

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SocksiPy_branch-1.01-py2.7.egg/socks.py", line 163, in sendall
  if 'encode' in dir(bytes):
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Does anyone understand where it comes from?

Comment: No one has a clue of what's happening there?

Answer (score 2):

For me it actually **failed** with `socksipy-branch` installed with pip.

However, it **worked ok after I downloaded socks.py directly** from http://socksipy.sourceforge.net/ to my working directory.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the SocksiPy library. I had the same problem and got it fixed by installing this library again directly from https://code.google.com/p/socksipy-branch/. The first time I installed it via `pip`.

Comment: Just tried to install it directly from tar.gz via its setup.py and it still crashes the same way.