# using tor with urllib python

Tags: python, ip, tor

I am trying to use TOR with Urllib as given in [How to change Tor identity in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887505/changing-tor-identity-inside-python-script). However I am not able to understand where shall I find the configuration files.

can anyone give  a easier solution so that I can generate new ips using TOR from python?

Comment: Could you describe exactly what you have done so far? And what are you error messages?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

import socks
    import socket
    def create_connection(address, timeout=None, source_address=None):
        sock = socks.socksocket()
        sock.connect(address)
        return sock

```
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)

# patch the socket module
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
socket.create_connection = create_connection

import urllib2

print urllib2.urlopen('http://icanhazip.com').read()

import mechanize
from mechanize import Browser

br = Browser()
print br.open('http://icanhazip.com').read()
```

Comment: But now, can't find how to renew the address

Comment: NOTE: The new SOCKS port seems to be 9150. I literally spent an hour, disabling the firewall etc. trying to figure out why it didn't connect...

Answer (score 0):

See stem's [client usage tutorials](https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/to_russia_with_love.html) for examples of making a python socket over tor. That said, please be careful about creating new identities. Doing so puts a high load on the Tor network (for more about this see [here](https://stem.torproject.org/faq.html#how-do-i-request-a-new-identity-from-tor)).