# Send NEWNYM to TOR with Java?

Tags: java, htmlunit, tor

anyone knows how i can send the NEWNYM signal to TOR through java code?

Say I have this:

```
        String adress = "http://some-adress";
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_52);
        ProxyConfig proxyConfig = new ProxyConfig("127.0.0.1", 9150, true);
        webClient.getOptions().setProxyConfig(proxyConfig);

        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
        HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage)webClient.getPage(adress);
```

And technically i can do this to restart the application, and get a new identity:

```
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/Users/user/Desktop/Tor Browser/Browser/firefox.exe");

        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("TASKKILL /F /IM firefox.exe");
```

But there must be a way to send the NEWNYM signal, because to get a new identity with TOR this way is quite messy.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I don't know tor nor HTMLUnit well enough to add an answer, but it looks like you should be able to craft a [WebRequest](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebRequest.html), use `setHTTPMethod` to make it a NEWNYM (assuming NEWNYM is the HTTP verb/method rather than a query parameter) then send it through your webClient's WebConnection

Answer (score 0):

HtmlUnit uses Apache HttpClient to connect to the server.

And according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33156557/184201), you can do it by directly calling:

> ```
> public static void torNewIP() throws Exception {
>    Socket socket = new Socket();
>    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(TOR_IP, TOR_CONTROL_PORT));
>    socket.getOutputStream().write(new String("SIGNAL NEWNYM\r\n").getBytes());
>    socket.close();
> }
> ```
>
> After enabling 'TOR_CONTROL_PORT'