# changing ip in iteration with tor python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tor

I want to change my IP everytime I run through loop. I am trying to achieve it with TOR. I have seen few posts with similar question, but solution given there is not working. So far my code looks like:

```
import socks
#import socket
import requests
import time


for i in range(1,3):
    socks.setdefaultproxy(proxy_type=socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, addr="127.0.0.1", port=9050)
    try:
        print (requests.get("http://icanhazip.com").text)
    except Exception as e:
        time.sleep(30)
        print (type(e))
        print (e)
```

I need different IP every time, instead of same IP.

edit : I have tried using approach given on [How to change Tor identity in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887505/how-to-change-tor-identity-in-python). My limitation is not to use any external libraries. also solution provided by Nedim is without external library.

so far I have tried following to get different IP from mentioned link:

```
import socket
import sys
import os

try:
    tor_c = socket.create_connection(("127.0.0.1", 9051 ))

    secret = os.urandom(32) # pass this to authenticate
    hash = tor_c.s2k_gen(secret) # pass this to Tor on startup.

    tor_c.send('AUTHENTICATE "{}"\r\nSIGNAL NEWNYM\r\n'.format(hash))
    response = tor_c.recv(1024)
    if response != '250 OK\r\n250 OK\r\n':
        sys.stderr.write('Unexpected response from Tor control port: {}\n'.format(response))
except Exception as e:
    sys.stderr.write('Error connecting to Tor control port: {}\n'.format(repr(e)))
```

but it is throwing following error:

```
Error connecting to Tor control port: ConnectionRefusedError(10061, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it', None, 10061, None)
```

Comment: I don't like your P.S. We don't provide solutions here, we provide help. Maybe "P.S. I'm using Python 3" might sound better

Comment: @YotamSalmon edited. sorry if it sounds rude. solution = help to answer question

Comment: Tor changes ip every 5 minutes. So you'll have to consider that.

Comment: @Simonhow come following post showing different IP in loop then ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887505/how-to-change-tor-identity-in-python

Comment: So how is your question different from the one you linked in the comment?

Comment: @interjayI have tried those solution but it is not working :(. may be it is python 2 compatible

Comment: By "not working", what error or symptoms did you get?

Comment: @drew010connection actively refused

Answer (score 1):

```
def renew_connection():
    with Controller.from_port(port=9051) as controller:
        controller.authenticate(password='password')
        controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
        controller.close()

def request_tor(url, headers):

    print((requests.get(url,proxies={'http': 'socks5h://localhost:9050'}, headers=headers)).text)
    r = requests.get(url)
    print('direct IP:', r.text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = 'http://icanhazip.com'
    headers = { 'User-Agent': UserAgent().random }
    for i in range(5):
        request_tor(url,headers)
        renew_connection()
        time.sleep(5)
```