# Python Socket Tor

Tags: python, sockets, proxy, mechanize, tor

I would like to change my id in tor with mechanize

Thats what I got right now:

```
import socks
import socket
import mechanize
from mechanize import Browser

def create_connection(address, timeout=None, source_address=None):
    sock = socks.socksocket()
    sock.connect(address)
    return sock

socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)


for i in range(0, 10):
    socket.socket = socks.socksocket
    socket.create_connection = create_connection
    br = Browser()
    print br.open('http://icanhazip.com').read()
```

How can I change my id everytime I request to the site?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I assume by `id` you mean IP address.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19809147/892493