# Changing external IP address in Python

Tags: python, ip, vpn

I have a python robot that accesses internet websites and performs some tasks (**using selenium and google chrome**). I would like make the python code to **change** my external IP address every, say, 10 interactions that the code performs in the websites. Is it possible? Would you have the adequate line of code for this task?
Note that the websites that I access recognize VPN, so when I try changing my IP address through VPN, I cannot access these websites.
Thank you

Comment: hello you can use tor expert bundle.
expert bundle: https://www.torproject.org/download/tor/
changing tor ip: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887505/how-to-change-tor-identity-in-python
make requests using tor: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30286293/make-requests-using-python-over-tor

Comment: The websites I have to access do not accept TOR either.

Comment: If you can't use TOR or VPN, then you can't change your IP. Your public IP is set by your ISP.

Comment: What is ISP? Does it mean that two different computers connected to the same internet network (wifi) will have the same public IP recogonized by the website that does not accept VPN nor TOR?