# How to run Multiple Tor Browser instances on windows?

Tags: proxy, tor, socks

I am trying to run multiple instances of Tor Browser on Windows with different `torrc` configuration and different ip addresses.

**Tor Browser version: 10**

OS: Windows 7

I have modified torrc file with `SocksPort` and `ControlPort`, also I have modified `extensions.torlauncher.control_port` and `network.proxy.socks_port` on the browser.

I am able to open multiple windows from the same TBB but unable to open separate instances with separate `torrc` config.

I have tried these options, but they don't work anymore.

https://gist.github.com/lethak/9a17a6e235e58013a644c6b20d8495b1

https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6846/multiple-instances-of-tor-w-tor-browser-since-v4-5?rq=1

https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/2006/how-to-run-multiple-tor-browsers-with-different-ips/6401#6401

[How to run multiple Tor processes at once with different exit IPs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321214/how-to-run-multiple-tor-processes-at-once-with-different-exit-ips)

Edit: Added screenshot of the error message , when tried to open multiple Tor Browser instances.

[image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a copy of your installed Tor directory. (For example copy to Tor Browser2)
Edit the file \Tor Browser2\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Browser\profile.default\prefs.js
In my example the socks port is 9250, the control port is 9251
`user_pref("network.proxy.socks_port", 9250);`
`user_pref("network.security.ports.banned", "9050,9051,9250,9251");`
`user_pref("extensions.torlauncher.control_port", 9251);`

[Here you can see that 2 Tor instances are running.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64P7D.jpg)

Comment: Is this answer dead? You said edit, what do you change? There is no port in that file, none of the things you posted about, and you didn't even give instructions on what to change, you just said to edit it. Edit with what? Are you saying to add that code to the end? I added it, but it didn't work, so these instructions either don't work anymore, or your instructions are wrong/insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Hello as far as i know there is nothing complicated to do this. Problem is that tor need different ports for each instance and does not provide automatically assign ports mechanism. i can do it on my own.

Just clone your tor directory. Start first intance and write: about:config

then find socks and control ports. change it. Close browser. Start again both instances and you are good to go.

THIS SOLUTION IS APPLICABLE TO BOTH: LINUX AND WINDOWS :)

Answer (score 0):

1. One can also use `about:config` interface to change the ports above (which will eventually add them to `prefs.js`).
2. In Debian taskbar icon of each instance can be set by removing `/usr/share/applications/torbrowser.desktop` and replacing `Tor Browser2/Browser/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).